# Python cost check (Closed)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am making a function that inputs weight and returns cost. My code is correct and I did my math but the cost being returned isn't making any sense

```
def cost_check(weight):
  if weight <= 2:
    cost = (weight * 1.50) + 20.00
  elif weight > 2:
    cost = (weight * 3.00) + 20.00
  elif weight > 6:
    cost = (weight * 4.00) + 20.00
  else:
    cost = (weight * 4.75) + 20.00
    
  return cost

print(cost_check(8.4))
```

when I call the function it is supposed to return 53.60. BUT instead it returns 45.2 for some reason, it is really frustrating

Comment: `8.4 > 2` so you get `(weight * 3.00) + 20.00`

Comment: ooh so if i make i put a limit to each of it then it should work? I'll try that

Comment: You check `> 2` before you check `> 6`. The `> 6` code will never be executed. You could just put the `> 6` chunk first.

Comment: Yes; currently `elif weight > 6:` and `else:` are unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not work because these statements will never be reached:

```
  elif weight > 6:
    cost = (weight * 4.00) + 20.00
  else:
    cost = (weight * 4.75) + 20.00
```

Suppose you have weight = 3. Then it will match the statement

```
 elif weight > 2:
    cost = (weight * 3.00) + 20.00
```

Because the next statements are elif and else they will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

ok so i changed it to:

```
def cost_check(weight):
  cost = 0
  if weight <= 2:
    cost = (weight * 1.50) + 20.00
  elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:
    cost = (weight * 3.00) + 20.00
  elif weight > 6 and weight <= 10:
    cost = (weight * 4.00) + 20.00
  else:
    cost = (weight * 4.75) + 20.00
    
  return(cost)
```

and it worked as it was supposed to, thanks anyways for the help guys!